# App Crashes When (insertItems) is Called The Second Time on CollectionView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

Basically the first time this runs it's perfect then the second time it crashes. I have some pictures that show which line of code it crashes on. The issue seems to do with perform batch.

**Code:**

```
  let ref = Database.database().reference().child("test")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            for snap in snapDict {

                if snap.key == "testValue" {

                    self.log.performBatchUpdates({

                        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: group.count, section: 0)

                        group.append("textHere") 

                        self.log.insertItems(at: [indexPath])

                    }, completion: nil)
                }
            }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add multiple new values in a loop but one at a time. It's much better to batch them all into a single insert.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("test")

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
        var newPaths = [IndexPath]()
        for snap in snapDict {
            if snap.key == "testValue" {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: group.count, section: 0)
                newPaths.append(indexPath)

                group.append("textHere") 
            }
        }

        if !newPaths.isEmpty {
            self.log.insertItems(at: newPaths)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't use Firebase but it is my understanding that its completion handlers are called on the main queue. If not, this code needs to be updated so this code inside `if let snapDict...` is run on the main queue.

Also note that you should create an `IndexPath` with an `item` and a `section` when working with a collection view. Use `row` and `section` with a table view.